# Sharing on Facebook for site with location based redirection shows unwanted name & description

Tags: php, facebook, redirect, geolocation

I have a website that redirects the user to a particular local subsite when you visit the index page.

For example, when you visit www.abc.com, I run a 'redirectCity()' function on the server side. If a city is detected, it directs the user to www.abc.com/newyork. If no city is detected, it directs the user to www.abc.com/city_picker. The meta data for www.abc.com/newyork is set for New York users, and the meta data for www.abc.com/city_picker is designed to be generic.

When I share the link 'www.abc.com' on Facebook, it's throwing me back the title, description and thumbnail for the 'www.abc.com/newyork' site.

Is there an elegant solution to have Facebook pick up the meta data from 'www.abc.com/city_picker' site instead?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**:
Facebook uses a special user agent. You can check for this user agent and show the generic page ([reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/)):

```
facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+https://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)
```

---

Well, Facebook (and basically all decent Web crawlers) try to view your websites the way a normal user would view it. And it seems that Facebook server that is scraping your page is in NY! :-)

Your best bet is to capture from which IP Facebook is accessing your website and make an exception, now I wouldn't do this. You may want to promote your Facebook Fan Page instead of a regular Like Plugin pointing to the "*Homepage*".